# Post method return false for both valid and invalid data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to create a login page but the authentication return same result for both valid and invalid data(it returns 'Invalid Username' for all cases). I checked everything but unfortunately couldn't catch anything. following are my code. I appreciate any help.

forms.py:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput({'placeholder': 'Enter Your Email', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput({'placeholder':'Password','class':'form-control'}))
```

views.py:

```
class IndexPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Athentication/templates/Athentication/index.html'

class LoginForm(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Athentication/templates/Athentication/login.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    def get(self,request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        if request.method =='POST':
            email=request.POST.get('email')
            password=request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(self.request, email = email, password = password)
            if user is not None and user.is_valid:
                login(self.request,user)
                return HttpResponse('valid Username')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Username')
        return render(request,template_name,{'form':form})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [path('', views.LoginForm.as_view(), name='login_page'),
               path('index/', views.IndexPage.as_view(), name = 'index'),
               path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
               ]
```

login.html:

```
<form method="post" >
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    {{form.email}}
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-lock-circle-open"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    {{form.password}}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox">
                  <input class="custom-control-input" id=" customCheckLogin" type="checkbox">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for=" customCheckLogin">
                    <span class="text-muted">Remember me</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary my-4" type="submit"  value="Enter"  />
                  
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: in your code user = authenticate(self.request, email = email, password = password) change self.request to request. And why do you need to check method=='POST' if you already in post()

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class()
    if form.is_valid():
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(self.request, email = email, password = password)
        if user:
            login(self.request,user)
            return HttpResponse('valid Username')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid Username')
    return render(request,template_name,{'form':form})
```

Comment: in your code `user = authenticate(self.request, email = email, password = password)` change `self.request` to `request`. And why do you need to check `method=='POST'` if you already in `post()` method of `TemplateView`

Answer (score 0):

wanted to comment but can't.
try changing `if user is not None and user.is_valid:` to `if user is not None and user.is_active:`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone but I found that the django built-in check and authenticate with username and I need to change the default to login users by email.